# The meaning of this include path syntax

Tags: php, syntax

I have a problem with configuring my app in a server and googling and looking around I landed on this [page](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/changing-the-include_path-in-a-script-or-the-custom-php-ini-file) which pretty much is my problem but I still don't know how to change this into my situation so could someone explain the syntax of this expression.

```
 include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php"
```

Comment: The dot `.` means the current directory and the colon `:` is a delimiter, separating the paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a linux `$PATH` specification. It's a list of folders, separated by `:`s, in which PHP will look for files which you try to `require` or `include`. `.` means the current working directory.

Comment: So does that mean I specifically mention the file being called with that url? or does the usr refer to user and I have to give the server user name and the like?

Comment: @altsyset `/usr` is a normal directory on *NIX systems. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: No, it only specifies where PHP will look for files you try to include, when you include them. Like if you call `require("foo.php")`, PHP will look if it exists in the local directory (`./foo.php`), then for `/usr/lib/php/foo.php`, then for `/usr/local/lib/foo.php`. Note that this happens in this order. If it then isn't found it will raise an error. `/usr` and `/usr/lib/` are normal system folders on Unix-like (e.g. GNU/linux) systems.

Answer (score 3):

That is just a colon-delimited list of directories that PHP will search for files that are called via `include()` and `require()` (and their `include_once()` and `require_once` friends). If you want to add your own directories you would add them as such:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/path/to/your/includes"
```

`/path/to/your/includes` is the sample path to where your included files will be

Comment: That is really helpful but I have to bring u down with me to the specific problem. The issue arises when this file, mpdf.php tries to call config.php with require(_MPDF_PATH.'config.php'); to solve this I added ini_set('include_path', '/config.php'); since both are in the same folder. But that didnt solve it yet? what am I missing?

Comment: If they are in the same folder just use `require('./config.php')`

Answer (score 3):

The `include_path` is all the paths in which PHP will look for the file when you use `include('file')` (or `require` or the `_once` derivatives). It is several paths separated by `:`. The `.` path is the current working directory.

So, when you `include('file.php')`, PHP will first look for `./file.php` (in the current directory), then `/usr/lib/php/file.php`, then `/usr/local/lib/php/file.php` and it will use the first file it finds.